# How to sort a List<LabelItem> while splitting a string ?

Tags: c#, sorting, split

I have a labelItem list that contains elements like : CARD1, CARD2, CARD10 ,CARD11

and I'm trying to sort them so I applied the sorting like below

```
 List<LabelItem> sortedList = _labelItems.OrderBy(x => x.ViewLabel).ToList();
        _labelItems = new BindingList<LabelItem>(sortedList);
```

But it  doesn't sort it perfectly because the presence of the string CARD so it returns the list like CARD 1 , CARD10 , CARD11, CAR19 , CARD2 ,CARD21

I know that there is many good tools on how to split a string while using a natural sorting algo  like in this link 
http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting

I'm finding it hard how to apply the split on this  labelitem ( remove the string card ) and sort the list and make it return CARD1 , CARD2 CARD3 , CARD10 ,CARD11,CARD20 instead of CARD1 CARD10 CARD11 etc....

I appreciate help

Comment: Is CARD then a number always in the name ?

Comment: Yes , Card is in the name then numbers increment once you click on the add card buttom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take out the string and convert the rest to a number:

```
List<LabelItem> sortedList = _labelItems.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ViewLabel.Replace("CARD", "")).ToList();
    _labelItems = new BindingList<LabelItem>(sortedList);
```

Note: This only works if you know that all your items start with word `CARD`. If they don't, you need to find out a way to get the numbers out of there

Comment: I appreciate your help , indeed they all start with CARD , they go CARD1 CARD2 etc..... Can't wait to try it out , much appreciated

Comment: I added an anwer to what I was exactly looking for , but still I deeply appreciate your answer , fact it will only work if my list contains only card , but I realise that it could contains other things

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for , Indeed like you suggested  Is good when I only have CARD in the list , then I discovered that No , it's not always a card It could be device and God only know what in the futur they might add

Plus , using like the basic sorting like the answer above will get the list sorted wrongly with ASCII sort

So the better approach is to implement like explained in http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

Then All I did is sorting my BindingList like that

`BindingList<LabelItem> sortedList = new BindingList<LabelItem>(_labelItems.OrderBy(x => x.Label, new AlphanumComparatorFast()).ToList());`

Comment: Thanks ! I wish I could upvote you twice had same issue and loved your approcah